# Exception thrown: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, sql, error-handling

I am following a Youtube video tutorial, so it should be straightforward with everything working since someone already worked out the errors....except since I am here you know it's not the case!

Here I am trying to add a feature that when you click on a cell box in a data grid `RoomsDGV` (in a form) it then brings the relevant data into a text box e.g `RnameTb`

The problem I am having is that these lines are bringing up an error when I click onto the cell:

`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Arg_ParamName_Name'`

I have no idea if this makes sense or if I have included enough information. I am very new to coding, C# and SQL... If anyone can shed some light on what is happening I would be very grateful!

```
 int key = 0;
        private void RoomsDGV_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            RNameTb.Text = RoomsDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            RTypeCb.Text = RoomsDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            StatusCb.Text = RoomsDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            if(RNameTb.Text == "")
            {
                key = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                key = Convert.ToInt32(RNameTb.Text = RoomsDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you understand what the error is and where this error can occur?

Comment: Without seeing how `RoomsRGV.SelectedRows` is filled, I would assume you need to access `Cells` from `0` -> `2` instead of `1` -> `3`

Comment: @hijinxbassist I don't understand the error. Are you able to explain what it means?

Comment: @JamesGould I tried this, no luck

Comment: @motxilles it means you're trying to access part of an array that doesn't exist. `SelectedRows` and `Cells` are both `Array`, or a `List` (same difference in this example). If you have 3 items in an array, they'll appear at `arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]`. If you try to access `arr[3]`, you'll get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. Have you stepped through with a debugger and tried to see what's in the arrays?

Comment: Lets say you have 3 items in an array (length 3), with index starting at 0 (zero based indexing). The valid range starts at the first index (0) and stops at the last index (length - 1).  The first item is at index 0., the second item is at index 1, the third at index 2.  So our range is 0 through 2 (0, 1, 2) = 3 items.  Out of range means you went beyond that range, either in the positive or negative direction.  -1 is not in this range, nor is 3.  If we say the index is 3, our argument (the index) is outside of the range (0 through 2).

Answer (score 0):

first check RoomsDGV.SelectedRows.Count()>0

then check RoomsDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells.count()

then check RoomsDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value!=null

if you directly assign value without checking then it will gives error